# High ranked college phD vs low ranked college phD, which one to choose?

Tags: phd, university, ranking

Does completing phD from a highly ranked university has benefits over completing phD over a lower ranked University? 
I am only talking about the college rankings and not about the advisor rankings like for eg: TAMU has better rank than UAH.

Comment: Please read [this answer of the linked question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/66927/546)