# What is important in choosing a Ph.D. program?

Tags: phd, graduate-school

I'm now choosing a Ph.D. program between two schools and am struggling a lot. Please let me know your thoughts and I'll greatly appreciate any help! The two universities are very similar in reputation and compensation.

1. School 1's lab: The professor is very nice and supportive. He would support a broad range of research topics and I have the freedom of choice. The students are very hardworking. They published 8 top conference papers last year.
   However, the students in this group are from not good universities. And the professor is very young, his oldest Ph.D. student hasn't graduated yet, so I don't know the students' outcome. Also, the students are so hard-working that the work-life balance might be bad. Also, the professor doesn't have as many connections in my desired place of work.
2. School 2's lab: The students in this lab are all from top universities. The professor has advised many Ph.D.'s and all of them are going to great labs and universities now. The professor has a lot more citations and more connections in the country I want to work in the future.
   However, the group only published 3 top conference papers last year. The professor is also not as committed to personally advising me.

Comment: Getting a Ph.D. is hard work, and there will be frustrating times. You'll need fierce enthusiasm to get you through those times. So I don't recommend committing yourself to work that you regard as "not as interesting".

Comment: Frankly, I don't think it is correct to judge the student from the university they graduated from. However, you should not rely on your colleague's skills for choosing the PhD positions. Maybe you should ask your self what drives you in choosing to enrol in a PhD position first of all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I've been admitted to multiple PhD programs, how should I choose between them?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/66926/ive-been-admitted-to-multiple-phd-programs-how-should-i-choose-between-them)

Answer (score -1):

> The students in this lab are all from top universities

it is an irrelevant criterion for choosing a Ph.D. program for your

> ... not as interesting

Unless you don't mind being miserable throughout your P.hD, you shouldn't work in this lab if you don't have to, which seems to be the case.

> ... the professor is very young

I think it is a plus, instead of a negative.

> the students are so hard-working that the work-life balance might be bad.

Just because they don't know how to balance their work-life with their life outside of work, it doesn't mean you won't be able to too.

Answer (score -1):

When you say "the students in this group are not from good universities" or "the students in this group are from top universities," what exactly does this mean?  Are you referring to the schools where they went to undergraduate, because its not unheard of for a student to go to a great PhD school from a not so ranked undergraduate (I've seen professors go from not so ranked state schools (or even schools outside the US) to top schools for their MS/PhD.

What matters between the two is how happy you would be at each school.  Ideally you want the most supportive advisor and a group where you would fit in.  Even if the group of students goes to/came from top schools, if you don't fit in you would probably be very unhappy there.  It's unwise to rule out a professor/advisor, just because they haven't graduated any PhD students yet (every professor has been in that position at some point in their career).

Based on what you have written, I would believe that the first option would be the best option.  You don't know that those top universities would absolutely be a fit for you (could be more toxic than you desire), plus you may find more of a fit in that group than you would with the other one imo.  Additionally, you mentioned that this group is of more interest to you, plus you and the professor have a more supportive relationship and there is more potential here, especially to publish.
But this is a decision that only you can make.