# Most important factors when selecting grad program?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, advisor, application, supervision

When selecting grad programs, is PI fit the most important factor?

I'm a prospective PhD student in the biological sciences and I need to choose between two programs. I'm struggling to prioritize the most important factors to guide the decision.

Program A has the best fit location both geographically and also in terms of the lab environment (new, clean, natural light). It also has the best fit as far as faculty, lab group size, and the vibe/values of the department. However the PI is a hot mess, and seems to be very disorganized. His students are jaded and they shared with me that he has dropped the ball on important things more than once. I am a very disciplined and organized person, and I struggle to work with others who don't have it together, *especially* when that person is my boss.

Program B has a very organized and on the ball PI who would be a great fit in terms of both mentorship and working style. However, the geographic location is an awful fit for me and the lab environment is grim (think leaky, isolated, dark, etc). There also aren't as many faculty who align with my research interests. This option does come with better access to resources and has slightly better funding, though.

Can a good mentor outweigh the rest? Or, conversely, can a great location and department outweigh the frustrations of working with a mentor who needs to be managed by their students?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/66926/ive-been-admitted-to-multiple-phd-programs-how-should-i-choose-between-them

Comment: I think it's too dependent on your personal values to say which factors are most important or how exactly to weight them against each other, but I think that canonical question will help to gather some different things you should be considering.

Comment: Are their other potentially interesting (and interested) PIs at those schools? Or are you accepted into a specific group, not just a department?

Comment: There are more questions here complaining about bad advisors than about bad facilities. Beware.

Comment: @JonCuster program A has more faculty I could see myself happy working with if things fell through with the PI there, which isn't out of the realm of possibility, but in my field you are accepted to the lab rather than the program and your advisor is relatively fixed from the beginning.

Comment: @BryanKrause I hear what you're saying. Thanks for sharing the other thread to look at.

Comment: I agree this decision will be down to the particulars of your particular situation. But, I suspect the key factor will be exactly what kind of things the bad PI has dropped the ball on. If the PI is well-meaning and responds well to being repeatedly prodded, then a certain personality type may work well with him. Whereas if the PI is hostile and non-responsive, that's a different matter.

Answer (score 2):

It is always a difficult choice as nothing is perfect.

I usually recommend to put priority on research topics and overall group atmosphere.

Sometimes people accept a bad or toxic atmosphere because of the standing of the group or the university, or the research topic. This is a personal choice, which I understand, but this is not for everybody. Some people will handle well, while some others will break down. You will also need to ask yourself if you would like a hands-on or a hands-off PI. This is important.

PI are not perfect, in general. I only met a handful of perfect PIs that would combine dedication, availability, reliability, helpfulness, and fairness, all together. If you can find someone that has two or three of those traits, then go for it. It will make your life much easier. A PhD is not easy, there is no need for more obstacle or difficulties.

In my opinion, geographical location should not be an obstacle. If you really like the PI and the research projects, then you should seriously consider this option. Of course, as you have not mentioned the location, it is difficult to say anything specific but it is also possible that the place really is a problem. Note also that a great location will not make your work PhD life easier. If you hate your work, you hate your work, regardless where you live.