# Concerning PhD application, I have been asked for an pre-interview call. What and how should I prepare?

Tags: phd, application

I have submitted an application for a PhD position recently. It required a few papers being published and two reference letters that can be sent directly to them, along with of course research proposal, CV and motivation letter.
It appears, one of the reference letters didn't reach them in time, and I have been asked to attend a pre-interview call. What kind of preparation should I be making? I could really use some advice, please help me out here!
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

It's okay to ask them what to expect if they haven't told you already: "who will be on the call?" and "is there anything I should prepare?" and "how much time should I set aside?" are all reasonable questions to ask.

I don't think a "pre-interview call" is something nearly standardized enough for anyone to guess otherwise.

Comment: Actually, it is possible that the call is to let the candidate know what to expect in the actual interview. Take notes if that is the case.

Comment: @Buffy Yep, certainly possible, but could also be what I know best as a "phone interview" which often comes before an invitation to an in-person interview for job applicants in many fields. We can all speculate and the only way to answer for sure is to ask. In the case you suggest then the response would be something: "It'll just be a 10-minute conversation to let you know what to expect in the actual interview, nothing you need to prepare."

Comment: @BryanKrause actually, PhD advisor/supervisor (main person under whom I would be doing it) will be on the call. Just him and I. I'm thinking question perhaps wouldn't delving deep into the "research proposal" but on the "behavorial" side like a few suggested on https://www.findaphd.com/advice/finding/phd-interview-questions.aspx  Please suggest!

Comment: @kern Everything is on the table that will help the advisor decide if you are a good candidate and good fit for a position. Remember that interviews are always two-directional in that you should be assessing your potential advisor/lab just as much as they assess you.

Comment: @BryanKrause work there is going to be so cool. I'm more like in "Can I just get in there, please" mode :) And, I'm sorry if I sound pestering way too much, but how can I assess him/lab?

Comment: @kern Start by reading some of the questions here that involve people in various stages of needing help with their advisor (of course these search terms are not perfect at narrowing down to that scenario, but you get the idea): https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=help+advisor Consider that most of these posts come from people who were just "trying to get in there" in one sense or another.

Comment: @kern Also here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/66928/63475

Comment: It's great @BryanKrause. I really appreciate it, thank you so much!