# Grad School Program Recommendations & How to Narrow Down My List of Programs

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, mathematics, statistics

I'm hoping to apply to graduate (MS) programs in statistics or applied math later this year, but frankly I'm having a hard time narrowing my list down and was hoping for some advice from people here. A bit about me, I have taken and done quite well in Calc II and III, Linear Algebra. I am taking Real Analysis and Probability in the Fall. I'm interested in Differential Equations and would love to take both ODE/PDE courses at some point. From a theoretical perspective I'm interested in Probability Theory and Stochastic Processes. I'd also like to dip my toes into Bayesian methodologies a la MCMC.

I'm currently working as a data consultant, so I'm very comfortable in SQL, decently comfortable in Python, and am learning/practicing R such that I'll be comfortable by the time I matriculate into a program.

As far as programs, I'd prefer to find a lower cost program or a funded program, and would love to find a research-centric program (or at least one with a thesis requirement) as well as I have multiple years of undergraduate research experience (albeit in Quantitative Psychology.)

I'm in the United States, so I've been looking at larger State/Research schools like Ohio State, Michigan, Wisconsin, North Carolina, etc. but am pretty open to programs abroad as well (i.e. Canada, Switzerland, Germany, France.)

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE. We do not recommend particular programs (see [here](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3657) for an explanation). Is there some aspect of the process of choosing a program that we might be able to help with?

Comment: Thank you! Happy to be here. I think I'm looking less for specific programs and more for what variables to consider (funding, curriculum, thesis/non-thesis, etc.) as I am currently a post-bacc student and thusly don't have an advisor. I'm looking at a large (~30) list of programs and could use some help on factors to help pare my list down.

Comment: So I think [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/66926) is our "canonical" Q&A on this topic; it's hard to give more personalized advice since we don't know you. For example: I usually advice prioritizing funding over almost everything else; the small differences in program quality is rarely worth the huge differences in cost. But maybe you are rich, who knows. Only other thing I would mention is to consider doing a PhD instead. It's a longer time sink, but PhD offers usually come with funding, and you can often leave with a master's if you decide not to pursue a research career.

Answer (score 0):

At the MS level, pretty much any [R1 university](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_research_universities_in_the_United_States) such as those you mentioned will serve you well. Most have large math faculties and offer a lot of course options. The one difference might be whether a thesis is required or only coursework. You can decide which is better for you, but think also about what your further goals might be. If you contemplate eventually earning a doctorate then you might as well apply for that now, rather than get an MS first.

Funding is normally available for doctoral students as a TA, but it is pretty rare for masters education. Cost at state universities depends on whether you are a resident or not. There can be quite a difference. Doctoral students generally pay no fees and residency isn't an issue.

Beyond that, think about where you want to live for a couple of years. Urban or rural? That affects your costs if you aren't funded properly.

There are some universities that have a statistics department separate from mathematics, so you might look at that after making some decision.